# Scientific Notation when using the toString function

Tags: apex

We have a field on the Account object that is defined as `Number(15, 0)`.  We send this field via a soap request to some middleware.

Before we send the value we are changing it to a string using the `toString()` function. Sometimes the soap request will send the scientific notation for the data in the field.

I have not been able to find any rhyme or reason to it. I thought that if we reached a large enough value in the field it would always convert to scientific notation but that is not the case. What can I do to normalize the behavior of this function?

Comment: None of the `Number` types in `Apex` (`Long`, `Double`, `Decimal`, `Integer`) have a `toString` method.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the [`toPlainString()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_System_Decimal_toPlainString) method?

```
Decimal myDecimal = 12345.6789;

System.assertEquals('12345.6789', myDecimal.toPlainString());
```